# Python module not found after installation

Tags: python, installation, module

I'm trying to install the python module netcdf4. I seem to have been able to do this successfully, but then I get the "module not found error" when I try to import it in python. Having looked at some similar questions, I suspect the issue has something to do with the path, but I don't know what do about that. Here's what happens specifically:

```
(base) C:\Users\jwmil>conda install netcdf4
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


(base) C:\Users\jwmil>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netcdf4 as pc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netcdf4'
```

Comment: maybe you have two Python installed and you install module for one Python byt later you run code in second Python. Every Python need own version of module. You may try to install with `python -m pip install netcdf4`

Comment: I just tried that and it gave the same error. Is there a way to check whether I have multiple versions installed?